# Использование темплейта в Java типа C<A,B extends C>

Tags: java, generics

Если имеется Java Класс:

```
public class DummyTemplate<S, D extends DummyTemplate<S,D>> {

S value;
D next;
public DummyTemplate(S value, D next) {
    super();
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
}


    public static DummyTemplate<String, DummyTemplate>  factory(){

    return  new DummyTemplate<String, DummyTemplate>(null, null);
}

}
```

Ошибка :`Bound mismatch: The type DummyTemplate is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <D extends DummyTemplate<S,D>> of the type DummyTemplate<S,D>`
хоть это валидная подмена типа.
Где тип D задан для того чтоб `factory()` точно возвращал тип который нужно: когда создаёшь подкласс, обьявляешь

```
public class DummyTemplateSubclass<S,  D extends DummyTemplateSubclass<S,D>> extends DummyTemplate<S, D>{
```

Вопрос в том как дать определение типу `DummyTemplate<String, DummyTemplate>`, если постоянно надо рекурсивно указывать шаблон?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DummyTemplate<S> {

    S value;
    DummyTemplate<S> next;

    public DummyTemplate(S value, DummyTemplate<S> next) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public static DummyTemplate<String> factory() {
        return new DummyTemplate<>(null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Тогда там можно будет вставить любой DummyTemplate.
Идея в том чтоб next  был всегда того же типа или субкласс и имел такое же знаачение

Comment: Тогда совсем нет смысла генерифицировать next. Исправил решение.

Comment: смысл в том чтобы при создании субкласса
public class DummyTemplateSubclass<S,  D extends DummyTemplateSubclass<S,D>> extends DummyTemplate<S, D>{
ограничить тип D как DummyTemplateSubclass<S,D>

Comment: Тогда можно указать такой шаблон <S, D extends DummyTemplate<S, ?>>.
Но он не спасет от передачи в экземпляр предка класса экземпляра потомка DummyTemplate<String, DummyTemplate<String, ?>> dummyTemplate = new DummyTemplate<>("str1", dummyTemplate2).
Зато спасет от обратного случая DummyTemplate2<String, DummyTemplate2<String, ?>> dummyTemplate2 = new DummyTemplate2<>("str2", dummyTemplate) //не скомпилируется.